# I'm having trouble with centering.... Again

Tags: css, image, slider, centering

I am trying to center my image slider to the center of the page but i cant make it work, can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

here is the code:

```
#conteudo{
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
}



/* @group Slider */

#slider {
overflow: hidden;
margin:0 auto;
height: 593px;
width: 1281px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

}

#slider ul li {
  padding: 0;
  height: 593px;
  width: 1280px;

}

/* @end */
```

And here is the link to the site:

[Link](https://www.essr.net/cdcomunicacao/al5580/Redo%20-%20Korridas/)

Also, how can i make the image transition smoother?

Answer (score 0):

remove the float:left; in #slider you cant center any elements with floats

```
#slider {
overflow: hidden;
margin:0 auto;
height: 593px;
width: 1281px;
text-align: center;
float: left; // remove this..
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much <3, any idea on how to make the transition smoother?

Comment: what do you mean, transition of?

Comment: can you click the check if my answer help you or you accept it as right, i need to have at least 50 reputation, thank you

Comment: from one image to the other

Comment: how do i adapt it to the one i have?

Comment: use twitterbootstrap... there is tutorial in website

Comment: did you accept that as correct? can you hit the accepting the correct answer, thank you